# Why is pypy3 slower than python

Tags: performance, profiling, pypy

In an attempt to run my code faster I thought pypy would be just the job. However, I am finding that it is actually slower for some of my code.

Can someone help me understand why this is the case?

This is the call (a weighted sum) that I have identified which is slower in pypy, which is the main method within a class, at line 663 of functions.py.

It is called 500000 times.

```
def __call__(self, verbose=False):
    if len(self.links) != self.weights.size:
        raise Exception(f'Number of links ...')

    super().check_links(len(self.links))
    inputs = np.array([link.get_value() for link in self.links])
    self.value = np.dot(inputs, self.weights)

    return super().__call__(verbose)
```

Here is the snakeviz view of pypy run with cProfile

[image: pypy profile]

And here is the snakeviz view run with python

[image: python profile]

EDIT: 20210612

@mattip I took your advice and tried a dot product in standard python (sdot). Here are timings with numpy dot (ndot) for python and pypy.

[image]

It is good that pypy sdot (0.299) is faster than python sdot (0.749) and faster than both ndots (1.075/4.165). However, what surprises me is that sdot (python lists) is faster than ndot (numpy arrays), with the python interpreter.

Why is that? I had thought that numpy was supposed to be an optimised, fast package for this sort of thing.

Here is the code:

numpy dot product

```
def runndot(runs):
    weightslist = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
    weights = np.array(weightslist)
    inputslist = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
    inputs = np.array(inputslist)

    for _ in range(runs):
        value = np.dot(inputs, weights)

    return value
```

python lists dot product

```
def runsdot(runs):
    weights = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
    inputs = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]

    for _ in range(runs):
        value = dot(inputs, weights)
    
    return value

def dot(inputs, weights):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(inputs)):
        sum += inputs[i]*weights[i]
    return sum
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using NumPy, which is written in C. In order for PyPy to use c-extensions like NumPy, it needs to jump through some hoops which make the python-c-python transitions slow. I am not aware of a quick replacement for using np.dot on PyPy, sorry. There is [work afoot](https://hpyproject.org/) to make it happen, but it will not be available for a year or two.

You may be interested in using Numba to speed up this kind of code.

If the shape of your array is small, you can hand-write the dot product in python, avoid NumPy, and be fast.

Comment: I'd thought as numpy is supported in pypy https://www.pypy.org/posts/2017/10/pypy-v59-released-now-supports-pandas-2261195727261691228.html it meant if would be fast. I'll try dot in standard python.

Comment: The last comment in that link mentions the FAQ answer: At the moment of writing (October 2017) the main drawback of numpy is that cpyext is infamously slow, and thus it has worse performance compared to numpypy. However, we are actively working on improving it, as we expect to reach the same speed when HPy can be used.